# Which file(s) do I use for an Android app built with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have followed this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/upload-bundle)  on how to upload an app to Google Play

I have built my app in Android Studio, tested it and it works. I now want to upload the app to Google Play, Amazon App store, Samsung Apps, my own website etc..

After following the instructions down to the bottom on how to sign my app, I click locate file which takes me to 'build\outputs\apk\debug' and the files are app-debug.apk and output.json.

Are these the files for my app and if I want someone to install my app from my website do they download both?

Edit-

After running build again I found another link further down which takes me to app-release.aab, this looks more accurate.

Is this file my app, does it just need to be downloaded on to an android device to run?

Comment: Go build>output>release>debug_apk

Comment: Did you sign your apk yet?

Answer (score 0):

.apk file is the file used for the app.
.aab is a bundle file it is used by app stores to distibute diffierent versions of the same app based on device.

I uploaded .apk file to my server. I can then download that file on my android device from my server and it will run the app.